# curious what is wrong with this if statement?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Could someone explain what is wrong with this "if statement"? I get:

> "lvalue required as left operand of assignment".

This does not work:

```
if ([[prepDataArray objectAtIndex:iNDEX] boolValue] = YES) {
        NSLog(@"HARD");
    }
```

While this works:

```
diffQ = [[prepDataArray objectAtIndex:iNDEX] boolValue];
    if (diffQ = YES) {
        NSLog(@"HARD");
    }
```

I do realize where the problem are and that the 'lvalue' indicate that i need to have something different on the left side but i do not grasp why and how to do what i want inside the 'if' statement as tried in the first example.

Would appreciate if someone nice could give me a hint :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ([[prepDataArray objectAtIndex:iNDEX] boolValue] == YES) {
    NSLog(@"HARD");
}
```

it's `==` not `=`

The first one doesn't work because you try to assign a `BOOL` (`YES`) to a message. The second one works because you try to assign a `BOOL` to `diffQ`. This is correct, but not the result you expect (comparing `diffQ` to `YES`)

Common programming error ;) I've done this a millions times

Comment: ohhhh a BIG thank you i should have known this as i have been struggling with this a while ago. I feel so stupid, especially as i have spent about 45 min to test around with this.

Comment: don't ;) the longer you spent on common bugs, the quicker you'll be a good programmer. It's like an inprint in you're brain forcing you the avoid common mistake for each line you write ^^

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with what @thomas said above, but let me add.

**Don't compare a bool to `YES`**. It's not that the `if` construct requires

```
if( some comparison statement ) {
      ....
}
```

That's not the case. The `if` construct has the following form:

```
if( a boolean value) {
      ...
}
```

It just happens that a comparison statement yields a boolean, so you put that in the `if` statement. 
In your case, `boolValue` already gives you a `bool`. You don't need to compare that against `YES` or `NO`. That's like doing `YES==YES` or `YES==NO` and it's completely redundant.

Just do

```
if ([[prepDataArray objectAtIndex:iNDEX] boolValue]) {
    NSLog(@"HARD");
}
```

Comment: +1. While this is completely correct, I find myself adding == YES when programming in Objective C. Even if it's useless (the compiler probably removes it) ObjC is a verbose language, message calls almost read like english sentences, so a little "more" is sometimes good. In C I never do it though.

Comment: Then why don't you write `(((x==YES)==YES)==YES)==YES`? I'm joking;)

Comment: I agree with both points - but sometimes the verbosity is definitely needed. To get the best of both worlds (and avoid the error the poster made) I always try to swap the parameters in a comparison ie. if(variable == YES) becomes if(YES == variable)